# Wireless troubleshooting using ZedAir H2 laptop

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I bought a brand new laptop called **ZedAir H2**, and then installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

The WiFi connection has some trouble searching for hot spot. It shows this message:

```
activation of network connection failed
```

I saw a tutorial about how to find the wireless chip using this command:

```
lshw -C network
```

The result is:

```
description: Wireless interface
physical id: 3
bus info: usb@1:7
logical name: wlx54c9df9b1f49
serial: 54:c9:df:9b:1f:49
capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8xxxu driverversion=4.15.0-23-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

So I have no idea what is the product name of my wireless chip.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb; rfkill list` terminal command.